# for loop outputs functional brackets

Tags: python

At my Python code, I have the following line:

```
init_segment = str([init_segment for init_segment in os.listdir(job_output_root + '/' + track) if init_segment.startswith("init-")])
```

If I output the variable, the "[brackets]" are included in the output, why that?
Currently, it looks like this:

> `/tmp/output/6 test/['init-a-aac_he_v2-de-mp4a.40.5_64000.m4s']`

where it should look like that:

> `/tmp/output/6 test/init-a-aac_he_v2-de-mp4a.40.5_64000.m4s`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the line where you print `init_segment` I think somewhere you are printing `'/tmp/output/6 test/' + init_segment`. Create a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the string representation of the list. You want a single string created from the *elements* of the list only; use the `join` method to create that string.

```
init_segment = ''.join([x 
                        for x in os.listdir(job_output_root + '/' + track)
                        if x.startswith("init-")])
```

Comment: That seems to work way better. Thanks!